# PHP Contact Form Issue - 302 Found

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a problem with my contact form. It is not showing any response even though I tried almost anything. When I try to debug with echo out, I only see empty array even though I hit the send button once I filled all the details. The other issue I saw in the network was 302 Found.

```
<?
php echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST); echo '</pre>';
?>
```

This is my form file story.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/5minReadCopy/styles/articles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="story" class="container-fluid">
                <h2 class="p-3 pt-2 text-center">Write your story</h2>
                <p class="pt-1 text-center">aaa</p>
                <div class="inner contact">
                        <div class="contact-form">
                            <form id="contact-us" method="POST" action="form_process.php">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 wow animated slideInLeft" data-wow-delay=".5s">
                                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form" placeholder="Name" />
                                    <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail"  class="form" placeholder="Email" />
                                    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="form" placeholder="Subject" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 wow animated slideInRight" data-wow-delay=".5s">
                                    <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form textarea" placeholder="Write your 5 minute story here"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="relative fullwidth col-xs-12">
                                    <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="form-btn semibold">SEND</button> 
                                </div>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </form>
                            <div class="mail-message-area">
                                <div class="alert gray-bg mail-message not-visible-message">
                                    <strong>Thank You !</strong> Your email has been delivered.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and this is my form_process.php file

```
    <?php


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $mailFrom = $_POST['mail'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    
    $mailTo = "hello@whatever.com";
    $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
    $txt = "You have received an email from ".$name.".\n\n".$message;
    
    mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers);
    header("Location: story.php?mailsend");
}
?>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Seems the request isn't reaching your form_process.php file. Are they in the same dir?
Are you using Apache? Do you have a .htaccess file or rules in Apache config file?

Comment: Hi, @domenickk thank you for the answer. They are in the same directory and I am using Apache. Where can I check .htaccess or rules in Apache config file? And what to look for :) ?

Comment: .htaccess files should be in the same dir your have your code, if present. The Apache config in Linux usually is found in these places:  
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
/etc/httpd/httpd.conf
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf  

Are you using plain php, meaning no frameworks?

You need to look for any <Rewrite> rules, that would explain the 302 redirection

Comment: I found three htppd.conf files and one had rewrite rule:

#LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so

.htaccess files are not in the directory where my code is :/

Comment: Code 302 does indicate that your server is setup to redirect form_process.php to another location. You can issue a request to form_process.php from Postman or similar app (there's probably a way to use curl too) and inspect the return headers to see where the request is being redirected. You can then use the final destination value as a hint to figure out which .htaccess file is responsible for the redirect.

Comment: Can you share the network requests when you submit the form? Also you could try and place a link in your story.php file: <a href="form_process.php?reached=true">Click</a>
and check if it reaches your other file.